# PostgreSQL: Valid variable names for functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I cannot find any definitive information on what constitutes a valid variable name in a PostgreSQL function.

I am assuming the function is written using `plpgsql`. I know I can use letters, numerals (apart from the first character) and underscores. Is there anything else?

Where is this documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implicitly stated in the [introduction to PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html).

> Identifiers are implicitly converted to lower case unless double-quoted, just as they are in ordinary SQL commands.

So a PL/pgSQL variable has to comply with the rules for [SQL identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I have found that I can use the `$` character. I am exploring whether to affix the `$` to my variables to more reliably distinguish them from column names.

Comment: @Manngo: the common convention is to use a prefix like `l_` for (local) variables and `p_` for parameters passed to functions to distinguish them from column names.